# When a web page loads, does the content with display:none affect the load time?

Tags: html, optimization, time, load, size

When a web page loads, does the content with display:none affect the load time?

I have a huge list in html with about 600 links assigned so the html page alone comes to around 450kb(excluding images~150kb), while the stipulated size of a page according to our server is 300 kb.

But the lists are divided into 4 main lists which toggle between display none to visible.
i.e.when list 1 is visible others are hidden.and so on.

So I was wondering how the load time of the html page would be affected by this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,It does affect the load time.
I too tried this on my own website,It took some time to load.even if the div was hidden

I suggest you to load it dynamically,using jquery or ajax ,put all those menu item or what ever images in a separate html file,and call it whenever required.

Save's load time but More Coding

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because it is loading the full html. You can see the html code in the browsers code inspector. And you see the images in the hidden-tags was loading.

You can prevent this by using javascript. Only load the images when clicking the active tab.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, can u please help me with the java script? like not load div2, div 3, div 4 when only div1 is active.

Comment: At first, you can load the default active tab, when the site opens. 
A way to load the other tabs is:
Create a .html file for every div.
By clicking div1, you load the html-code to div1 (div1.html) and insert the html at the correct place.

Comment: For example:  
`function readFile() {  
 document.ReadURL.readFile(theLocation);  
 setTimeout("showFileContent()",100);  
}  
  
function showFileContent() {  
 if (document.ReadURL.finished==0) {  
  setTimeout("showFileContent()",100);  
  return;  
 }
 fileContent=document.ReadURL.fileContent;  
 document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = fileContent;  
}`

theLocation is the location to div1.html, div2.html, div3.hml

Comment: So i have to create separate html files for each div anyhow? thanks again.

Comment: You can also insert the html code directly with "innerHTML". But the clearer way is to create seperate files.

Comment: I think that is the safest bet. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. The browser loads html and parses also the hidden elements. They are also part in the internal "element-tree" of the browser. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to reference them e.g. via JavaScript to modify them.

Comment: So should i just create a separate html for every main div and load them separately? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Florian Kasper wrote some possible solutions you could try. I guess you won't get along only with static code. Modifying the "element-tree" of the browser (=DOM) dynamically via JavaScript is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of couse it affects the load time visibility in the DOM. The ammount to download is still the same.

To improve this you could use:

- Pagination (will_paginate in Rails, https://github.com/onassar/PHP-Pagination php)
- Infinite scrolling(will load the content dynamically during scrolling)
- AJAX loading of the lists

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have no idea how i'm going to use this.:/